# Cannot post my php file, using xampp

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to set up an HTML contact form on my website that will use PHP to send the information entered into the form to my email address.

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error that says `Cannot POST /form.php` and I can't figure out why.

I looked through similar questions that were asked here on StackExchange and the number one cause seemed to be that the PHP file wasn't in the same folder as the `index.html` file. However, both of my files are in the same folder; `newwebsite/index.html` and `newwebsite/form.php`.

So, why could this be happening?

Here's my `index.html` form:

```
<form method='post' action='form.php'>
                <label>Name: </label>
                <input type='text' name='vistorName' id='form-name' placeholder="Type your name.." required>
                <br>
                <label>Email: </label>
                <input type='email' name='vistorEmail' id='form-email' placeholder="Type your email.." required>
                <br>
                <label>Msg: </label>
                <textarea type='text' name='vistorMsg' id='form-msg' placeholder="Type your message here..." required></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type='submit' action="submit" value='Submit' id='submit-button' required><br>
            </form>
```

And here's my `form.php` file:

```
<?php
    //Pulling values that were entered into the form.
$name = $_POST['visitorName'];
$email = $_POST['visitorEmail'];
$message = $POST['visitorMsg'];

//Structure of email that I will receive with the form info
$email_from = "myemail@email.com";
$email_subject = 'New Contact Form Message';
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name. \n".
                "Here is the message: \n $message".

//Sending to my email address and using the mail function
    $to = "zcericola@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

//Validating the form
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
                        '(\r+)',
                        '(\t+)',
                        '(\%0A+)',
                        '(\%0D+)',
                        '(\%08+)',
                        '(\%09+)',
                        );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";

    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
        return true;        
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

if(IsInjected($email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}





?>

//HTML confirmation that message was sent.
    <html lang='en'>
    <h1>Your email has been sent. Thank-you!</h1>



    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have an action attribute on the submit button type? Also where does the error you say come from??

Comment: There is a typo here.
$message = $POST['visitorMsg']

Comment: You're not calling `isInjected` check before sending the email so it's useless. also your not validating it's even an email address first before presuming someone trying to inject headers, need to take a step back.

Comment: @Akintunde- The error comes after I fill out the form and hit submit.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Okay, so I should move isInjected above the email function. As for injecting headers, excuse my ignorance but I added that according to a tutorial. If it isn't necessary to get the form working, then I will do away with it.

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications, your code worked on my server.

Per Akintunde's comment, your form has typos in the field names:

```
<html>
<form method='post' action='form.php'>
                <label>Name: </label>
                <input type='text' name='visitorName' id='form-name' placeholder="Type your name.." required>
            <br>
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type='email' name='visitorEmail' id='form-email' placeholder="Type your email.." required>
            <br>
            <label>Msg: </label>
            <textarea type='text' name='visitorMsg' id='form-msg' placeholder="Type your message here..." required></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type='submit' action="submit" value='Submit' id='submit-button' required><br>
        </form>
```

Your "form.php" checks the e-mail address after attempting to send the e-mail.  Also, html comments are identified differently than php comments. I made those two changes.

```
<?php
//Pulling values that were entered into the form.
$name = $_POST['visitorName'];
$email = $_POST['visitorEmail'];
$message = $POST['visitorMsg'];

if(IsInjected($email))
{
echo "Bad email value!";
exit;
}


//Structure of email that I will receive with the form info
$email_from = "myemail@email.com";
$email_subject = 'New Contact Form Message';
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name. \n".
            "Here is the message: \n $message".

//Sending to my email address and using the mail function
$to = "zcericola@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

//Validating the form
function IsInjected($str)
{
$injections = array('(\n+)',
                    '(\r+)',
                    '(\t+)',
                    '(\%0A+)',
                    '(\%0D+)',
                    '(\%08+)',
                    '(\%09+)',
                    );
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";

if(preg_match($inject,$str))
{
    return true;        
}
else
{
    return false;
}

}



?>
    <html lang='en'>

<!-- HTML confirmation that message was sent. -->
    <h1>Your email has been sent. Thank-you!</h1>

    </html>
```

Comment: Okay, I did as you have suggested and just copied and pasted the edited code but it's still giving me the same error. I fixed the $message = $POST['visitorMsg'] and made it $message = $_POST['visitorMsg]. I should be using the name attribute to get the values correct? Not the HTML ID, or am I confused?


Edit: Also, when I open the console on the Cannot POST /form.php page after hitting submit, I get this error:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). If that helps anything.

Comment: Can you see if the error is produced by the browser or by your server?

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I think it is the browser, not the server.  When I refreshed and tried it again, the error in  Apache/Xampp went away but there is still an error in the console on chrome, saying server responded with 404 (not found).

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a configuration problem within your XAMPP setup.

Comment: Is there anything I need to do within Xampp and the apache server as regards to configuration? As it is now, it points to port 80 which is the default I guess. Sorry if I sound clueless, this is my first foray into servers.

Comment: What URL are you using in the browser window to bring up your form?  Should be http://localhost/{something}

Comment: localhost/newwebsite/form.php